# Add legend in GNU Plot

Tags: gnuplot, gnu

I have a plot with six different colorline in the same graph in GNU. Now my problem is to give description of the each line in the right side of the graph i.e. I have to add legend.

What command will be useful for this problem?
Eg: I have to add legend as the figure attached:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable the legend with

```
set key
```

and add a descriptive title to each line of your plot. E.g.:

```
plot x title "simple x function", x**2 title "quadratic function"
```

Comment: ..Suppose red line implies "X", blue line for "y" & so on..Now I am unable to show it on the top of the graph.